# Tizen XMLHttpRequest via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I am writing a Tizen app (web app/Javascript) for Samsung Gear S2. I am trying to send XHRs, and this works fine as long as connected via WiFi. However, when connected to my phone via bluetooth, there is an error and the connection can't be established.
I have read different information that this might not be possible at all / not be possible due to an SDK bug / only possible when routing the information through an Android app on the phone / etc.
Does anyone of you know what the issue is and how it may be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the internet privilege in config.xml file?

Comment: Yes: `<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>`, but that doesn't have any influence. As mentioned, via wifi it works...

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth interface is managed by the SAP (Samsung Accessory Protocol) and you could the SAP SDK to achieve what you want.

http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/setup-sdk